# AD Email Address is inaccessible in ASP.NET website on Server ONLY

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, iis, active-directory

I currently have an intranet website set up using IIS. It uses Windows authentication. It looks to Active Directory to get a user's email address through the following two lines of code :

```
        Dim userStr, userEmail As String
        userStr = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString
        userEmail = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress
```

Then, this email is used to send an email via SMTP client. My problem is that, when my website is hosted on our server, the email address seems to be inaccessible. This code works perfectly on my localhost. I have my page set up to show the email address once it is accessed, and it just remains blank on the server.

Can anyone tell me what could be going on? It also seems that some of my events are not firing, but I think that is due to the empty email address.

Thank you

Comment: Is the server it is hosted on a member of the domain?

Comment: Yes. It is a virtual server on our site's domain. It has multiple other web applications hosted on it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following code, which works:

```
            Dim userStr, userEmail As String
            userStr = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString
            Using HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()
                Dim ctx As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
                Dim xUser As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userStr)
                userEmail = xUser.EmailAddress
            End Using
```

It turns out the the code in the original question was trying to return the email address for the identity I am using in IIS. By using this code instead, I am able to return the current user's email address.